# Jackson Subclass serialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, immutables-library

I'm using an java API that I do not own and cannot modify. That API defines a class `Aggregation` which is a `Immutables` (immutables.github.io) abstract class with Jackson serialization and deserialization.

The class looks like

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonSerialize(as = Immutable_Aggregation.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = Immutable_Aggregation.class)
public abstract class Aggregation {
```

I want to add a field to Aggregation which should be picked up at serialization time, but instances of which can still be passed to methods accepting `Aggregation`.

I want to do something like:

```
public abstract class ExtendedAggregation extends Aggregation {}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't managed to inherit between two classes marked with `@Value.Immutable` as you would like, so I tried to use Jackson to solve the issue instead.

Found the following approach, which uses the `@JsonAppend` annotation and mixins to add properties without touching the `Aggregation` class.

First, define a mix-in class with the annotation:

```
@JsonAppend(
    attrs = {
        @JsonAppend.Attr(value = "version")
})
public class AggregationMixin {}
```

Register the Mixin with your `ObjectMapper` instance:

```
mapper.addMixIn(Aggregation.class, AggregationMixin.class);
```

Serialize the class by creating a dedicated `ObjectWriter`, in which you specify the value of the added property:

```
ObjectWriter writer = om.writerFor(Aggregation.class).withAttribute("version", "42");
...    
String output = writer.writeValueAsString(aggregationInstance);
```

The `@JsonAppend` annotation can be configured to obtain its value in a multitude of ways. Consult its documentation for details.

Some further reading :

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations#jsonappend
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations